# How to intercept navigation event in DOM?

Tags: html, dom, navigation

I have one case to intercept all navigation operation web page and do customized action then stop the navigation.

I managed to intercept all "click" event on "" tag. But there is some other situations to navigate current browser window such as modifying **window.location**.

So, is there an general approach to intercept navigation event?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload however, I'm not sure the support in all browsers...  This would also get called when closing the browser or tab, so might not be the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks, but unload event cannot be preventDefault. onbeforeunload event might helps.